# ServerSideRowModel - Remove filters and sorting at once without causing calls to `dataSource.getRows` twice

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We have a scenario where we need to remove column filter and sorting and then `purgeServerSideCache`.

Issue with that is, when we do `filterManager.setFilterModel(null)` and then `gridApi.setSortModel(null)`, two separate calls for `dataSource.getRows` are getting fired - which I would like to avoid.

What can I do to remove filter model and sort model so that `dataSource.getRows` method gets called only once?

Comment: You can set up your `getRows` function with a [`debounce(..., 0)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce). This way, the function should only run once. If you're doing async stuff `0` might not work, try `50` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation, https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-server-side-model-configuration/#configurations,

> `blockLoadDebounceMillis`:    Prevents blocks loading until scrolling has stopped for the specified number of milliseconds. When row count (i.e. lastRowIndex) is known, setting this property will enable skipping over blocks when scrolling.

`blockLoadDebounceMillis` of `gridOptions` can be used to set debounce timing for scrolling. Same can also be used here. Ultimately it is used to set debounce timing for `dataSource.getRows` method.